# Gradebook import in moodle

Tags: php, mysql, moodle

I am planning to use a separate quiz engine for moodle, since the quiz module for module has very less user friendliness and my staffs find it very difficult to create/edit questions. Now that I am using a different quiz module, I still want to integrate the grades with the grade book module of moodle. The gradebook import documentation is found missing from this link http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Gradebook_import

Can somebody help me with importing my gradebook in csv format to moodle? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

To import grades into moodle I think that you have to specify existing activities to update the grades. You would have to create a poodle quiz as a gradebook place holder. Then specify that activity to replace. Alternatively you could develop in an outside program then export your questions then use one of the quiz modules dozen or so import formats to import the questions. Users would then take the quiz in moodle bout development would happen externally.